# Google Merchant Customer Review Optin window not opening on order success page

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have integrated following code in my website order success page via GTM :

```
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>
  <script>
  window.renderOptIn = function() {
   window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
    window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
    {
      "merchant_id": 87654376,
      "order_id": "{{dl.order.id}}",
      "email": "{{dl.order.customerEmail}}",
      "delivery_country": "{{dl.order.deliveryCountry}}",
      "estimated_delivery_date": "{{dl.order.estDeliveryDate}}"
    });
});
```

}

I implemented a dataLayer in  my page which is propagatting the needed variables in above code just fine. The above tag is firing just fine.

But the optin window for google merchant customer reviews is not opening. When above code was pasted in site html then the optin window was opening fine. But when implemented the above code through GTM, despite the tag being firing OK, the optin window is not opening. Please help.

Comment: Please help. I am still waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since you posted the question. As I've run into similar issue - everything was set properly in GTM, but no badge or pop-up on checkout success page.

As it's seems - it can't be run through GTM - only directly.

Hope this will help and save time to others :)

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Partners-Support/Google-Customer-Reviews-set-up-through-GTM/td-p/1142177#

Answer (score 0):

The official Google help page has added a statement regarding GCR and GTM recently:

*"Google Tag Manager currently cannot be used for the opt-in code integration."
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9352538*

Let's hope that "currently" means there is some kind of development going on.